# UWP Using GetBindingExpression with x:Bind

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, win-universal-app, xbind

I am rewrite my UWP Application from Binding to x:Bind. I have a TextChanged Event on different Textboxes. With Binding I could use GetBindingExpression to update the Model. Is there an equivalent Methode for x:Bind? Or how could I make it with x:Bind?

```
    public void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var binding = ((TextBox)sender).GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
        binding.UpdateSource();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to do this before without success. I think is not available for now, because Bind it's just a markup extension.
Here is the documentation and examples how to use it
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt204783.aspx

Answer (score 0):

> The [`FrameworkElement.GetBindingExpression`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement.GetBindingExpression);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore,Version%3Dv5.0);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) method returns the [`BindingExpression`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.data.bindingexpression.aspx) that contains information about a single instance of a [Binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.data.binding.aspx).

So this can only be used in Binding. According to your posted code, it seems you want use x:Bind to update source when the text changed. In Binding, we can set [`UpdateSourceTrigger`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to `PropertyChanged` to do this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="200" Margin="5" />
```

But there is no `UpdateSourceTrigger` property for x:Bind and it only triggers on lost focus. So I suggest you keep using Binding in this case.

Comment: This advise is almost correct but is misleading in 2020, I'm not sure when the issue described here was fixed, even if it was a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Compiled Bindings `x:Bind` are directives that are executed at design time to generate code to register event handlers and explicitly set the relevant properties, bypassing the `{Binding}` registration that uses reflection at runtime, so at runtime there is no way to detect or get a handle to the binding statement from an `x:Bind` because there is none.

As partially explained by [@Jayden](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35738892/1690217), it is not necessary to obtain the binding at all in your specific case, as it is not necessary to manually/explicity call update on the binding when the text is changed, to do so is counter intuitive and leads to unexpected results.

The correct way to ensure that immediate changes to the `Text` property of a `TextBox` are comitted back through a traditional *TwoWay* `{Binding}` or a compiled *TwoWay* `{x:Bind}` is by setting the `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`.

> in UWP, both `{Binding}`and `{X:Bind}` support *UpdatteSourceTrigger*, however `{X:Bind}` has a simpler implentation with limited options, however both *do* support `PropertyChanged`

Both of the following would work:

```xml
<TextBox Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
         Width="200" 
         Margin="5" />
<TextBox Text="{x:Bind VM.Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
         Width="200" 
         Margin="5" />
```

The ONLY time that you would manually update the binding is if your binding statement has set the `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `Explicit`.

> The reason that you should not try to manually update binding is because it will conflict with the binding statement, especially if the binding is deliberately set to `UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus`. In this case your event handler will still update the binding on text change, when or if this becomes a problem for developers in the future they will not think to look for explicit handling of the text changed event

**As part of a migration to compiled bindings `x:Bind` and acknowledging that they could be used for any bindings, you should carefully review all calls to `GetBindingExpression()` in your code and try to elminate them as `GetBindingExpression()` is no longer a reliable mechanism to determine if a `DependencyProperty` has been configured, or to get the binding statement for a `DependencyProperty` at runtime.**

*I am aware of **one** standard control (`NumberBox`) that does not properly support `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`, however due to the fact that you cannot determine if a compiled binding has been used to bind a property other solutions need to be used to affect the changes that we are expecting, [see this post for solutions to `NumberBox`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64002911/1690217)*