# How to work around UpdateSourceTrigger ignored in NumberBox

Tags: uwp, binding, uwp-xaml

I have tried to set `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `PropertyChanged` on a data bound [NumberBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/number-box) in a UWP application.

My data form paradigm is to not show the *Save* button until there is a data change to actually save, but
as the data source is not updated until focus leaves the control, the save button does not become available until after the user moves to a different input control first.

- user cannot click on the save button because it is disabled, and so does not trigger a focus change.

This is the minimal example, if you use the spinners to change the value, the button is available, if you only type into the control you have to click the button twice, once to enable it (to commit the value change) and then once again, now that the button is available.

> If `UpdateSourceTrigger` is not working, how can commit the change so the user can click the button the first time when it *should* be available, so before focus change?

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="App3.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App3"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:muxc="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Page.DataContext>
        <local:DataClass/>
    </Page.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <muxc:NumberBox Value="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SpinButtonPlacementMode="Inline"/>
            <Button IsEnabled="{Binding NotZero, Mode=OneWay}" Click="Button_Click">Click if Not Zero</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

```cs
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace App3
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        public DataClass Model { get => this.DataContext as DataClass; }

        private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var msg = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog($"Value: {Model.Value}");
            await msg.ShowAsync();
        }
    }

    public class DataClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public double Value
        {
            get => _v;
            set
            {
                _v = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Value)));
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(NotZero)));
            }
        }
        private double _v;
        public bool NotZero { get => _v != 0; }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default behavior of `NumberBox`, which is usually used to make some judgments on the content in `NumberBox` after input is completed.

In the [control style definition of NumberBox](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/master/dev/NumberBox/NumberBox.xaml#L117), the main body is `TextBox`. If you want to intervene in this process, you need to get this `TextBox`.

**1. Viusal method defined**

```cs
public static class StaticExtension
{
    public static FrameworkElement VisualTreeFindName(this DependencyObject element, string name)
    {
        if (element == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
        {
            return null;
        }
        if (name.Equals((element as FrameworkElement)?.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return element as FrameworkElement;
        }
        var childCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(element);
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++)
        {
            var result = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(element, i).VisualTreeFindName(name);
            if (result != null)
            {
                return result;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**2. Attach TextChanged handler**

Xaml

```xml
<muxc:NumberBox ... Loaded="NumberBox_Loaded"/>
```

Xaml.cs

```cs
private void NumberBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var box = sender as NumberBox;
    var textBox = box.VisualTreeFindName<TextBox>("InputBox");
    textBox.TextChanged += TextBox_TextChanged;
}

private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string text = (sender as TextBox).Text;
    bool isNumber = !text.Any(t => !char.IsDigit(t));
    if (isNumber)
    {
        double.TryParse(text, out double value);
        if (value != Model.Value)
            Model.Value = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: It just super sucks that is doesn't respect the `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` like every other data entry control, but that's the best solution I can hope for, thankyou very much!

Comment: This discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64165206/1690217 highlights why I think this is a bug in the behavior of `NumberBox`. But I now understand how using `x:Bind` could further complicate how to achieve this internally, as the UpdateSource information is not available to the internal implementation if the input control is indirectly bound to the externally visible `Value` property.

Comment: It's ridiculous that NumberBox STILL doesn't bind the same way as a standard TextBox.

Comment: Is it the default behavior of NumberBox? where is it documented?